# Getting back a reversed string

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have used the simple way to reverse a string which is `my_string[::-1]`. However, I want to get back the string after reversing. So is there a simple approach to get it back again?

Comment: Ok you question is not really clear. You have the solution to reverse a string. Where is the problem? When you want the return then assign it to a new variable?

Comment: my idea is that I have sender and receiver. I want to send info in reverse way but when the receiver gets the string he should received it not in reversing way.

Comment: @Mark you want that the message be reversed in mid way? well you have to put the middle man in there somehow or make the receiver reversed it before given it to the user like in any encryption protocol...

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. So you will always "have" your string:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> s[::-1]
'cba'
```

Your string `s` is still there:

```
>>> s
'abc'
```

because `s[::-1]` creates a new string.

Comment: my idea is that I have sender and receiver. I want to send info in reverse way but when the receiver gets the string he should received it not in reversing way.

Answer (score 2):

```
See this easy solution:

>>> s = 'Mark'
>>> b = s[::-1]
>>> b
'kraM'
>>> s
'Mark'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the reversed string to get the original string value back.